# Can I use $1 in regex_replace?

Tags: c++, regex, replace, c++11

From reading the FCD for `regex_replace` (28.11.4) I can only *guess* that the function can also **use parts of the original string for replacing?** I can not test it with my gcc, is this correct?

```
using namespace std;
regex rx{ R"((\d+)-(\d+))" }; // regex: (\d+)-(\d+)
cout << regex_replace("123-456", rx, "b: $2, a:$1");
// "b: 456, a:123"
```

As you can see, I assume `$1` and `$2` refer to the *"()" capturing groups* (and not `\1` and `\2` like elsewhere).

**Update.** So, I guess this is a two-part question

- **Is this use of *capturing groups* in the replacement text supported at all?**
- **Is the default ECMAScript syntax using `$`*n*?** Or `\`*n*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table 139 in the C++ 2011 FDIS lists two constants that can be used to affect the rules used for the format string in [`regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace), `format_default` and `format_sed`. `format_default` is described as using "the rules used by the ECMAScript replace function in ECMA-262, part 15.5.4.11 String.prototype.replace." This standard does indicate the use of `$` for backreferences. See: [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Using the `format_sed` flag instead uses the rules for the sed utility in POSIX. Sed doesn't appear to support `$` backreferences.

Comment: Very well pointed out and directed to the standards. It seems that the boost interpretation is wrong. I think I will ask there for an opinion, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised; $ is not in the basic source character set (2.3). The [Dinkumware documentation](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx?manual=compleat&page=lib_regex.html#back%20reference) for TR1 states that it's indeed `\1`, and it's dialect-dependent.

Comment: But $'s are inside of a string.

Comment: Yup, for that see 2.14.5. A string literal can contain less characters (no \, " or newline as they have special meanings). You'd need to write it as `"\u0024"`

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question should be a two-parter: Is this feature available at all, and is it used with `$` or `\`?

Comment: @towi: Anything wrong with the docs I linked? `\1` should work (even in the BRE (POSIX) dialect).

Comment: @MSalters: Well, TR1 ist not exactly FCD. So I want to be sure. For example the "partial match" feature has been removed, as far as I know. Also, your link pointed to "back reference" which is for the "pattern" not the "replacement" -- look at the bottom of that page and you find "format flags". There you find "$n"... and thus, my guess is that it *is* in fact "$1" for the replacement text. Additional link, boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/regex/example/snippets/regex_replace_example.cpp, look at usage of `$&` in `format_string `